# How to fix Pending XHR Requests made after a websocket was opened?

Tags: websocket, electron, chromium, angular-httpclient

I am developing a Application which uses Electron with Angular as Frontend and node/express as Backend. For realtime Updates i use websocket connections, anything else is JSON Api with HTTP Calls on the Same Server Socket.

When i open my APP, it establishes a websocket connection and can access HTTP Calls afterwards, but sometimes the HTTP Requests just keep in pending state, because they use the same connection ID as the websocket connection.

I can not post images, so only have a link to DevTools Network Output:
(https://www.3dmedium.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/network.jpg)

the connection "websocket" is to an other Port
the connection "localhost" is websocket to localhost:8080
the get_chip is a http-client call to localhost:8080/get_chip

the `get_chip calls` which are working are the ones testing `AllowOrigin`... "preflight"

sometimes after a websocket reconnect (still ConnectionID 0) the http client calls use a other ID and are then working.

**electron is in Version 4.2.2**

**angular is in version 8.2.2**

**The Angular Service uses:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

.....

constructor(private http: HttpClient ) {
this.wsConn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080', ['soap', 'xmpp']);
}

....


this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/get_chip', data ).toPromise().then((result) => {
     console.log(result);
});
```

I think it has nothing to do with the Server side.... but thats the essential initialization code:

```js
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';

const app = express();
let server = app.listen(config.server.port);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });
```

**Is there any way to force Chromium/Electron to not use a pending connection which is used by websockets?**

Comment: OK, i think i misunderstood the Stalled state in Chrome. It can mean anything.....

Chrome starts a TCP Connection, and sends the request. Still there is no connection ID in Dev-Tools. Because of a Bug in my Server Application there is never sent an answer back.
So When Chrome should actually be in Waiting State, after Going through Stalled, DNS Lookup, Initial Connection, Request sent, it is still showing Stalled. Chrome Updates the state with starting of "Content Download"